Recognize exchange's solana addresses
As in this question, I see that there is no way to understand if a solana wallet address is part of an exchange deposit address. Does anyone know of a list of known exchanges deposit addresses or other ways to identify them?

Like the accepted answer said, you can't really do that yourself. However, you can take a look into Solscan's API documentation. They have plenty of exchange addresses that they have labelled, and you see it when you search any exchange address on Solscan. For example, the public name marked for this wallet is "FTX", as it belongs to FTX: https://solscan.io/account/6ZRCB7AAqGre6c72PRz3MHLC73VMYvJ8bi9KHf1HFpNk
The API is paid however.
You might be able to find maybe few more explorer API which have exchange addresses labelled manually by the developers, but there is no automated/standard way to identify it.
